# Mapear Pagina Inicial SpringMVC

Tags: spring, jsp

Olá!

Gostaria de mapear uma página inicial usando springmvc

´Tenho esse método:
Meu

> **Controller**

```
public class Treinamento {
    @RequestMapping("/inicio")
    public String inicio(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

no meu

> **web.xml**

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>inicio</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

Como para mapear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Treinamento {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String inicio(){
        return "redirect:index";
    }
}
```

Comment: mas eu gostaria de chamar do controller rs

Comment: Vc pode mapear / e redirecionar para index no seu controller então.
Seria isso que vc gostaria?

Comment: isso mesmo.. deu certo. Obrigado e eu só precisei do return "index"